# Change Location of a Panel when a button is clicked in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Good morning. I am having difficulty changing the location of a panel when a button is clicked. I am using VS 2012 and using the vb.net language. I tried to use the Location function, but I get these errors:
'Location' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel'.              Type 'Point' is not defined.
What other function should I use to change the panel's location upwardly?
These are the events when I click a button:

```
Protected Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    'lblname.Text = TextBox1.Text
    'lblemail.Text = TextBox2.Text
    'lblprof.Text = DropDownList1.Text

    Panel1.Visible = True
    lblname.Text = TextBox1.Text
    lblemail.Text = TextBox2.Text
    lblprof.Text = DropDownList1.Text

    TextBox1.Visible = False
    TextBox2.Visible = False
    DropDownList1.Visible = False
    Button3.Visible = False
    Label1.Visible = False
    Label2.Visible = False
    Label3.Visible = False
    Label4.Visible = False
    Button2.Visible = True
    Panel1.Location = New Point(480, 100)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the kind of control positioning that I often see in Web applications but if you want to do it, you can try something like this:

```
Panel1.Style.Add("position", "relative");
Panel1.Style.Add("left", "100px");
Panel1.Style.Add("top", "-150px");
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! I have to use style and add next time, but how come vb.net didn't recognize Location or New Point?

Comment: These properties are not implemented by ASP.NET Web controls. The positions follow the layout given by the flow of the HTML elements, and can be specified with CSS styles. The `Location` property sounds more like WinForms programming.